# Flutter Row() 'crossAxisAlignment != CrossAxisAlignment.baseline || textBaseline != null': is not true. Failed assertion:

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter i am getting error while using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline`

Error::

```
Failed assertion: line 3791 pos 15: 'crossAxisAlignment != CrossAxisAlignment.baseline || textBaseline != null': is not true.
```

code::

```
 Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,

    children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            '192',
            style: kBoldNumberText,
        ),
        Text(
        'cm',
        style: kLabelText,
        )
    ],
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 'textBaseline != null' after flutter upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129511/error-textbaseline-null-after-flutter-upgrade)

Answer (score 23):

While using `crossAxisAlignment` in flutter we need to tell what element to align, for that we can use `textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic` in alphabetic or if it is graphical

```
//alphabetic:::

textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
```

-or-

```
//graphic:::

textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic
```

in my case its `alphabetic:::` so i re-write

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic, ////<-- HERE --> ////
    children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            '192',
            style: kBoldNumberText,
        ),
        Text(
        'cm',
        style: kLabelText,
        )
    ],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to insert the following: `textBaseline: TextBaseline.aplhabetic`

In your case,

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic //here
    children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            '192',
            style: kBoldNumberText,
        ),
        Text(
        'cm',
        style: kLabelText,
        )
    ],
    )
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also added `textBaseline: TextBaseline.idiographic`.

Here is the code:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
  children: const [
    Text(
      "190",
      style: kNumberTextStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      "cm",
      style: kIconTextStyle,
    ),
  ],
),
```